# TinyMCE update content_style

Tags: javascript, angular, tinymce, tinymce-4

I'm using the Angular wrapper for TinyMCE 4, initializing the editor with some custom css like this:

```
editorInit: Settings = {
  menubar: false,
  statusbar: false,
  toolbar: false,
  content_style: '.highlight {background-color: #fff877;}'
};
```

I'd like to dynamically change this content_style later, for example like this:

```
editor.settings.content_style = ".highlight {background-color: none;}";
```

However, this change is not being applied. Do I need to re-initialize the edior somehow everytime I want to change the content css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I don't want to re-initialize the whole editor I went ahead and updated the style tag manually. Of course you should make sure that you're updating the correct one, here's a simplified version:

```
editor.iframeElement.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('style')[1].innerHTML = `
  .highlight {
    background: none;
  }`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the editor is loaded you cannot dynamically load different CSS - once TinyMCE processes the configuration it won't re-examine those variables.

You can certainly use `remove()` and `init()` to re-initialize TinyMCE.

With the Angular we provide you likely need to reload the component that includes TinyMCE to get the remove/init cycle to happen.